# How to configure python in Vim or Gvim?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, vim

I've installed gvim 7.4, vim 7.4 as well as python 2.7 and python 3.5. I would like to use vim on the console with python 2 or python 3 support, however, I'm having problems configuring this. Vim doesn't show python 2 or python 3 support when I run the versions command but gvim does. How do I configure Vim to use the python library? I can confirm that both versions of python and vim are 32 bit and also that these have been added to the %path% environment variable. I did :versions on the gvim console and it showed it compiled python 2.7 and python 3.2 but I have python 3.5 installed which might be why vim doesn't have python support?

Comment: Have you tried downgrading python to 3.2 ?

Comment: I uninstalled 3.5 and installed 3.2 and vim recognizes it in features when i do vim --versions in console but when I do :echo has('python') and :echo has('python3') it still returns 0. 
EDIT: I was wrong about running vim --versions and it recognizing python. I use Windows and in Ming64 i run vim --versions and it does recognize python but cant use it and in cmd it still shows  a "-" next to python and python3 for vim